# How to localize family/given name order and spacing in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, localization

I'm sure I saw a new api call for this in ios7 in which you would put in the given name and family name and it would spew out how it should be displayed depending on the locale, but I can't seem to find the call again, even after hours of searching.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) what you're looking for?

ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName
Returns the localized name of a person property

```
CFStringRef ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName (
   ABPropertyID property
);
```

Parameters: property - The person property whose localized name is being returned.

Return Value: The localized name of property.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, that's coming from the Adress Book.  I need something where I put in first Name and last Name and I get <firstName>_<lastName> for english and <lastName><firstName> for chinese.  I'm pretty sure I saw this but I forget where.

Comment: Could this work for your purposes though? You could make a new ABPerson, set the first name and last name and then call that function.

Comment: Actually, I was looking into that, that might also work since there is now the call ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormatForRecord since iOS7, maybe that was what I had seen. I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: @thewormsterror Did you find an answer for how to determine whether or not there should be a space between the given name and family name? (The Contacts app seems to omit a space for names consisting of only Chinese characters and puts in a space if there is at least one English character, so the names would be formatted correctly if you have a mix of English and Chinese characters. This suggests that the method works without any reference to a locale.)

Comment: @user2135004 Actually I did, but never tested it out. In iOS 7, there is the call ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormatForRecord(), and ABPersonCopyCompositeNameDelimiterForRecord()

Answer (score 0):

Get a person record(ABRecordRef) from the address book, then use

```
NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
```

This will print out localized version of name similar to the iPhone contacts.

Thank you [thewormsterror](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375658/thewormsterror) for your comment. It led me to right way.